# How can i pass button name or value to controller by using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Controller code

```
public ActionResult FirstFloor()  
{
   var eachWorkStation =
         from prog in db.Zona1
         where prog.System == "Z012"
         select prog;

   return View(eachWorkStation.Take(3).ToList());
}
```

how can i pass button name or value (like Z011, Z012 and Z013 etc) to controller, without using form,
i am new to mvc

Thank you
Your help will appreciated!

Comment: What language or framework is this?

Comment: What 'button(s)' are you referring to. You need to show your view and how you pass the value (ajax/form submit etc). Your method does not even have a parameter to accept the value so its unclear what your doing (your claim that _code is working fine for only one button_ is not correct - your not referring to any button value - its just a hard coded value)

Comment: Yes i did wrong, its working for hard code only

Comment: <button onclick="LinkTo()" class="btn1 " name="Z011 " value="Z011">Z011</button>

Comment: i am not using  form, and LinkTo() is referring table model

Answer (score 1):

This question is very vague but try this.

```
public ActionResult FirstFloor(string buttonName)  
{
   var eachWorkStation =
         from prog in db.Zona1
         where prog.System == buttonName
         select prog;

   return View(eachWorkStation.Take(3).ToList());
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain how variable `buttonName` gets populated in MVC—it can be a querystring parameter, or an input name in a POST, and I think it might work from other sources too (cookies? Session? Hmmm there was some issue here).

Comment: True but without the rest of the code or an explanation of at least how this section of code is being used I can't do that.